# SQL71501 error when using MERGE

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I imported an existing database into a Visual Studio database project (VS2017). One of the stored procedures uses a `MERGE` statement that has a `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT` clause.

Unfortunately, this is causing problems with Visual Studio, which can't seem to resolve some of the columns in the `VALUES` portion of the statement. Here's the exact error:

> Error SQL71501: Procedure: [dbo].[spOvernightImportRating] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[tblAmountType].[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblAmountType].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblImportPolicy].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblImportRating].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblImportSettings].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblPolicy].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID], [dbo].[tblPolicy_EffectiveDate].[AmtType]::[AmountTypeID] or [dbo].[tblPolicyGenerationDetail].[AmountTypeID].    MGA_BMS.DB
>   C:\Users\tomh\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\MGA_BMS.DB\MGA_BMS.DB\Stored Procedures\spOvernightImportRating.sql   77

The relevant part of the code:

```
MERGE dbo.tblPolicyGenerationDetail
        USING
        (
            SELECT 
                PGM.MaxPolicyGenerationID AS PolicyGenerationID,
                AmtType.AmountTypeID,
                R.ClassCode,
                R.[Description],
                CAST(COALESCE(R.Amount, '0.00') AS DECIMAL(14, 6)) AS Amount,
                CASE WHEN COALESCE(R.ApplyMode, '0') = '0' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS ApplyMode,
                CAST(COALESCE(R.ModifiedAmount, '0.00') AS DECIMAL(14, 6)) AS ModifiedAmount,
                CAST(COALESCE(R.CommissionMGA, '0.00') AS DECIMAL(14, 6)) AS CommissionMGA,
                CAST(COALESCE(R.CommissionBroker, '0.00') AS DECIMAL(14, 6)) AS CommissionBroker,
                CAST(COALESCE(R.NetPremium, '0.00') AS DECIMAL(14, 6)) AS NetPremium,
                P.PolicyID,
                PED.PolicyEffDateID
            FROM
                dbo.tblImportRating R
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblImportPolicy IP ON
                IP.IsProcessed = 0 AND
                IP.IsValid = 1 AND
                IP.TransactionID = R.TransactionID AND
                COALESCE(IP.RecordType, '') = 'P' AND
                IP.Transaction_Type IN ('New', 'Reinstate', 'Renew')
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblImportSettings S ON S.ProgramID = IP.PROGRAM_ID
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblPolicy P ON P.CarrierPolicyID = IP.CARRIER_POLICY_ID 
                AND P.ProgramID = CAST(IP.Program_ID AS INT)
                AND (R.MGA_POLICY_ID = P.MGAPolicyID or(S.RequireMgaPolicyID = 0 AND coalesce(R.MGA_POLICY_ID, '') = ''))
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblPolicy_EffectiveDate PED ON PED.PolicyID = P.PolicyID AND PED.TermNumber = CAST(IP.TermNumber AS INT)
            INNER JOIN (SELECT PG.PolicyEffDateID, MAX(PG.PolicyGenerationID) AS MaxPolicyGenerationID FROM dbo.tblPolicyGeneration PG GROUP BY PG.PolicyEffDateID) PGM ON PGM.PolicyEffDateId = PED.PolicyEffDateId
            INNER JOIN dbo.tblAmountType AmtType ON AmtType.CalculationType = R.AmountType
            WHERE
                R.IsProcessed = 0 AND
                R.IsValid = 1 AND
                CASE R.AmountType
                    WHEN 'Class' THEN S.AggregateClass
                    WHEN 'Premium' THEN S.AggregatePremium
                    WHEN 'Fee' THEN S.AggregateFee
                    WHEN 'Tax' THEN S.AggregateTax
                    WHEN 'Deposit' THEN S.AggregateDeposit
                END = 0 --Only Control records
        ) AS [source] ON 1 = 0
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (PolicyGenerationID, AmountTypeID, ClassCode, [Description], Amount, ApplyMode, ModifiedAmount, CommissionMGA, CommissionBroker, NetPremium)
        VALUES (PolicyGenerationID, AmountTypeID, ClassCode, [Description], Amount, ApplyMode, ModifiedAmount, CommissionMGA, CommissionBroker, NetPremium)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.PolicyGenerationDetailID, INSERTED.AmountTypeID, [source].PolicyID, [source].PolicyEffDateID INTO @IDs;
```

I've read several other posts on this sort of error, but none seemed to apply to this specific situation. Any suggestions? Has anyone else seen this issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using aliases throughout the query.  Alias the target.  Specify the source alias in the `VALUES` clause.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I already tried adding an alias in the VALUES clause. That seems to confuse VS and I get an error for an unresolved reference to tblPolicyGenerationDetail.AmtTyp

Comment: Because you aliased the table as `[source]` not as `[tblPolicyGenerationDetail]`

Comment: Thanks Jacob, that led me to a solution! If you want to put that into an answer then I can select it. I just had to add `[source].` as the aliases.